# How is a DC battery’s voltage distributed across the components in an ideal wire?

Tags: voltage, batteries, dc

If the sum of voltage drops in a circuit is equal to the battery's voltage, then how do the electrons maintain their flow after passing the voltage-dropping components if the components had already dissipated all the electric potential energy the electrons had?

Comment: the voltages balance out so there is still some voltage left to push the electrons through the wire back to the battery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is a DC battery’s voltage distributed across the components in an ideal wire?

When current flows through a resistance, there is a voltage drop across that resistance that is proportional to the current and to the resistance.

$$V =IR$$.

A real (non-superconducting) wire has resistance, and therefore current cannot flow through it without there being some voltage drop.

But your question is specifically about *ideal* wires. In ideal wires, there is \$0\$ resistance, and therefore there is no voltage drop from one point to another, even though current is flowing through the wire. That is just a property of "ideal" wires.

> how do the electrons maintain their flow after passing the voltage-dropping components if the components had already dissipated all the electric potential energy the electrons had?

Once we leave the world of real wires with their real resistances, and enter the world of ideal wires, we no longer worry if the physics doesn't work out. We just accept that our assumptions allow current to flow in the absence of any potential difference.

Answer (score 0):

The battery aka the energy source has to move it back up to a higher voltage. If voltage is like gravitational potential energy, the battery is like a lift or pump that moves the electron back up the hill to let it roll back down. Also voltage is relative. Just because you consider an altitude to be 0, does not mean that there isn't an even lower point.

I guess someone felt this analogy was a complete answer, so there it is...

Answer (score 0):

The chemical reaction in a battery produces an excess of electrons at the negative terminal and a deficiency of electrons at the positive terminal.

Electrons in the wire attached to the positive terminal are attracted to the terminal leaving a net positive "field" behind.

At the same time, electrons in the wire attached to the negative terminal are repelled by the terminal.

So the electrons are being pushed and pulled at the same time. Like a belt between two pulleys that carries anergy from the motor to the load, the cascade of electrons around the closed circuit carries the energy from the battery to the load, but they do not slow down. The velocity (and the current) is the same throughout the circuit, just like the velocity of the belt is the same from one pulley to the other and back again.

Comment: The mean velocity of the electrons is not constant throughout a circuit unless the conductivity is constant throughout the circuit